# How to dlopen the dependencies of a library that is to be dlopen-ed?

Tags: c, linux, dlopen

I've got two shared object:

1. `libbar.so`, in which a function `int bar(char const*)` is provided;
2. `libfoo.so`, in which a function `int foo(char const*)` is provided, and this `foo` function would call `bar` inside; consequently, `libfoo.so` depends on `libbar.so`.

Both of them are stored in nonstandard paths, say `/whatever/path/to/libfoo.so` and `/yet/another/path/to/libbar.so`. I'd like to `dlopen` these libraries and invoke `foo` in my program.

I attempted with this demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    char const* libbar_path;
    void* libbar_so;
    int (*bar)(char const*);
    char const* libfoo_path;
    void* libfoo_so;
    int (*foo)(char const*);
    char const* err;

    libbar_path = get_libbar_path();
    libfoo_path = get_libfoo_path();

    libbar_so = dlopen(LIBBAR_SO, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if ((err = dlerror())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open libbar: %s\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    bar = (int (*)(char const*)) dlsym(libbar_so, "bar");
    if ((err = dlerror())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to lookup for bar: %s\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("main bar: %d\n", bar("hello dlopen!"));

    libfoo_so = dlopen(LIBFOO_SO, RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if ((err = dlerror())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open libfoo: %s\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    foo = (int (*)(char const*)) dlsym(libfoo_so, "foo");
    if ((err = dlerror())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to lookup for foo: %s\n", err);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("main foo: %d\n", foo("hello dlopen!"));
}
```

However, when I compiled and ran this program with `gcc -ldl demo.c -o demo && ./demo`, it successfully loaded `libbar.so` and invoked `bar`, yet then complained about not finding `libbar.so` when it tried to `dlopen` `libfoo.so`:

```
$ gcc -ldl demo.c -o demo && ./demo
bar: hello dlopen!
main bar: 19
failed to open libfoo: libbar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**My Question is:** Is `dlopen` able to load the dependencies of libraries to be `dlopen`-ed later? If so, how? I must have missed something.

FYI, versions of related tools on my system:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Comment: You will need to provide the compile time library search paths as part of your command line (e.g. add `-L/whatever/path/to -L/yet/another/path/to`) and you still need to pass `-rpath` to the linker, e.g. `-Wl,-rpath=/whatever/path/to,-rpath=/yet/another/path/to` so the directories are added to the runtime library search path. (see [man 1 ld](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html))

Comment: You need to also set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directories where libbar.so and libfoo.so are stored before running your compiled binary. e.g. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/whatever/path/to/:/yet/another/path/to/`

Comment: @GauravPathak Is it possible to update library search path during runtime? I wouldn't be able to know where the libraries locates before the program is deployed and on different containers the paths vary.

Comment: @KarlLiu but in your question code, you declared a macro pointing to the exact library files. `#define LIBFOO_SO "/whatever/path/to/libfoo.so"` and 
`#define LIBBAR_SO "/yet/another/path/to/libbar.so"`. So, that will be the path to your deployed libraries

Comment: @GauravPathak Actually it was just a minimal demo that reproducing my problem. In my situation these paths are unknown while compiling. Probably I should update my demo to prevent being misleading.

Answer (score 0):

> Is dlopen able to load the dependencies of libraries to be dlopen-ed later?

Yes.

> If so, how?

By using absolute paths to the libraries, e.g.

```
void *h1 = dlopen("/yet/another/path/to/libbar.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOW);
void *h2 = dlopen("/whatever/path/to/libfoo.so", RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NOW);
```

Note: since `libfoo.so` requires a symbol from `libbar.so`, the latter should be loaded *first*.